Understanding Standard variance value vs Expectation value scatter plot graph
I am dealing with the following scatter plot graph of expected and standard variance values of different distances for 100 randomly chosen pairs of intervals:

Here $d_I, d_{Hm}, d_E$ and $d^H_{L1}$ represent different metrics on intervals.
As I do not have a statistical background, I do not understand what the graph is telling me. I have a basic idea of how to calculate the expected value and standard variance for a given data set, but that doesn't help me much here, as I am unable to understand the graph.
What I aim to do:

To understand how the graph has been plotted by decoding the math behind it from the basics.
To reproduce the graph on my own with suitable software.

A guideline or an explanation would be highly appreciated.

What is standard variance?

@ZackFisher Source: https://doi.org/10.1007/s40815-023-01571-5 (pg-26)

But that paper never defined "standard variance". I've never encountered this term in any statistical papers / books.

@ZackFisher I agree. That's why I couldn't understand the graph.
